# unable to copy data from mongodb to elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mongo-river

I have followed the documentation online to copy data from mongodb to elasticsearch using river plugin.

My Elasticseach version is 1.4.2
My MongoDB version is 2.6.6

I have setup my mongodb to run as a replica set.
I have installed the latest following plugins:

```
bin/plugin --install com.github.richardwilly98.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/2.0.5
bin/plugin -install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments/2.4.1
```

Then I started elasticsearch and used the following command to create a new index from mongodb database

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_river/mongodb/_meta' -d '{ 
  "type": "mongodb", 
  "mongodb": { 
    "db": "MPTEST", 
    "collection": "datasets",
    "gridfs": false
  }, 
  "index": {
    "name": "mappr", 
    "type": "datasets" 
  }
}'
```

After that, I could see the following log messages in my elasticsearch console:

```
[2014-12-20 20:49:34,785][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] MongoDB River Plugin - version[2.0.5] - hash[c11c5ae] - time[2014-12-18T12:08:22Z]
[2014-12-20 20:49:34,786][INFO ][river.mongodb.util       ] setRiverStatus called with mongodb - RUNNING
[2014-12-20 20:49:34,788][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] River mongodb startup pending
[2014-12-20 20:49:34,819][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] Starting river mongodb
[2014-12-20 20:49:34,820][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] MongoDB options: secondaryreadpreference [false], drop_collection [false], include_collection [], throttlesize [5000], gridfs [false], filter [null], db [MPTEST], collection [datasets], script [null], indexing to [mappr]/[datasets]
[2014-12-20 20:49:34,838][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Mantra] [mappr] creating index, cause [api], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
[2014-12-20 20:49:34,949][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Mantra] [_river] update_mapping [mongodb] (dynamic)
[2014-12-20 20:49:35,006][INFO ][river.mongodb            ] [Mantra] Creating MongoClient for [[localhost:27017]]
```

Now my question is, aren't the documents existing in mongodb copied over to elasticsearch at this time ? If not, then when I a do a mongorestore to populate my collections in mongo, will those documents get copied over ? If still no, then how can I copy the data in bulk ? Or is it something that I missed that I am not able to get the data copied over ?

Comment: I don't know what it's doing, but it appears that it does not copy data? Try doing a query against `mappr`: `curl -XGET localhost:9200/mappr/_search`. If you get results back, then it's work.

Comment: I tried that. It gives zero hits. The datasets collection in mongodb MPTEST database has a lot of data. Also I tried saving a doc from mongo shell and tried checking if it got copied to elasticsearch but still nothing

Comment: Any errors on your ES console at that point? And have you tried without `"gridfs": false`?

Comment: tried both gridfs false as well as true. No errors on ES console

Comment: also tried `"options": {
      "secondary_read_preference": true
    }`

Comment: @mandeep_m91 did you got a message index created:true ? also install head plugin to keep a track of indices and river.

Comment: I will install head plugin. And yes I did get index created:true

Comment: Have you enabled replicaSet and your oplog is got updating ?

Comment: As this guy here ^ mentioned, make sure you have enabled replicaSet, also make sure you are using the correct version for the river plugin.